# No Wordpress Admin Login or FTP access?

Tags: wordpress, authentication, admin

I have a client wanting me to create a whole new WP site for them but with most of the same content as their current WP site. The issue is they don't know their current WP admin login or their ftp login (via DreamHost), and their previous web guy is MIA. Is their any other way to gain access to their site to export their WP data? I figured no, but I thought I'd at least ask.

Answer (score 1):

Contact the hosting company. They can give you access. They're usually pretty cooperative about that kind of thing. As long as you can prove you own the site.

Comment: Will the site's content be accesible via ftp or is that only able to be exported from within the WP admin dashboard? My main concern is being able to use the existing site's content.

Comment: You will be able to access the database information and, if nothing else, dump the database information and inject it into a new site.